# How to Test useEffect Fetch with Jest in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

How do I test my useEffect Fetch with Jest in React? I've tried looking for answers and found a code that I copied to try out but am still failing the test. I haven't used Jest before and am currently trying to implement it in a code I'm working on.

Here is my test inside my test.js file:

```
  it('Displays days from 1 to 31', async () => {
    expect(useEffectTest).toBe([{ day: 1 }]);
  });
```

And here is the useEffect in another component called calendar.jsx:

```
 const useEffectTest = () => {
  const [daysData, setDaysData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5001/chocolates')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => setDaysData(data));
  }, []);

  console.log(daysData);
};
```

I want to test if the fetched api is acquiring this data from an array of objects:

```
{ day: 1, status: 'empty' || 'open' }
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to update your unit test to call your function, like this:

```js
it('Displays days from 1 to 31', async () => {
    expect(useEffectTest()).toBe([{ day: 1 }]);
});
```

That's because `expect` needs to have the data returned from your `useEffectTest` function passed in to it.

However, this will still fail because your function isn't returning anything. So we need to update `useEffectTest` to return `daysData`, like this:

```js
 const useEffectTest = () => {
  const [daysData, setDaysData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:5001/chocolates')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((data) => setDaysData(data));
  }, []);

  return daysData;
};
```

Next up, we usually don't want to make network requests from unit tests. That's because network requests can make unit tests slow, and brittle. For example, if your API server goes down, we would still want the unit tests to pass. To get around these problems we need to mock the fetch request. A popular way to mock fetch requests is with the [jest-fetch-mock](https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock) library.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for the help :) Sure glad to learn something new